# Changing a variable value written on a php file with symfony console components

Tags: symfony

I am new to symfony components .
I am creating a cli app with `symfony console component`

I have my own file for database connection.

initial file

```
<?php

// Some other stuff
$databases = array ();
// Some other stuff
?>
```

Output file i want to generate

```
<?php

// Some codes
$databases = array (
    array (
      'database' => 'my_database',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
);
// Some other stuff
?>
```

I search every where but couldn't find any solution. how to do it with symfony components?

anyone having any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: what are you looking for exactly? how to write in an existing file in php?

Comment: I want to replace `$databases = array ();` with corresponding array

Answer (score 0):

You can use [var_export()](http://php.net/var_export) to do this.

How you go about inserting that in the proper place is the challenge. Unless you want to go down the lexer/parser route, you can possibly use some basic string substitution.

```
$dbConnections = array (
    array (
      'database' => 'my_database',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
);
$configFile = 'path/to/config.php';
$configFileContent = file_get_contents($configFile);
$configFileContent = str_replace(
    '$databases = array ();',
    '$databases = ' . var_export($dbConnections, true)
);
file_put_contents($configFile, $configFileContent);
```